# How to pass an entire ViewModel back to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel that contains two objects:

```
public class LookUpViewModel
{
    public Searchable Searchable { get; set; }
    public AddToSearchable AddToSearchable { get; set; }
}
```

The two contained models look something like this:

```
public class Searchable
{
    [Key]
    public int SearchableId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AddToSearchable> AddedData { get; set; }
}

public class AddToSearchable
{
    [Key]
    public int AddToSearchableId { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public int SearchableId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Data { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Searchable Searchable { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view that uses my `LookUpViewModel` and receives input to search for a `SearchableId`. If the `Searchable` object is found, a `LookUpViewModel` object is created and passed to the View. The view then displays editor fields for `AddToSearchable.Data`. Once submitted, I want the `LookUpViewModel` to be passed to an action method to handle all the back-end code. The only problem is, the `LookUpViewModel` passed to my action method contains a null reference to `Searchable` and a valid reference to `AddToSearchable`.. i.e. I'm missing half of my data.

Here's an example of what my view looks like:

```
@model HearingAidTrackingSystem.ViewModels.LookUpViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("LookUp", "Controller", "idStr", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="idStr" id="idStr"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}

@if (Model.Searchable != null && Model.AddToSearchable != null)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("AddMyStuff", "Controller"))
    {
        Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Searchable.SearchableId);
        Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Searchable.AddedData);
        Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddToSearchable.AddToSearchableId);
        Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddToSearchable.SearchableId);
        Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddToSearchable.Searchable);

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddToSearchable.Data)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddToSearchable.Data);
        </div>                                    

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
}
```

and here are my action methods:

```
public ActionResult LookUp(LookUpViewModel vm)
{
    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LookUp(string idStr)
{
    int id = /*code to parse string to int goes here*/;

    Searchable searchable = dal.GetById(id);
    LookUpViewModel vm = new LookUpViewModel { Searchable = searchable, 
                                               AddToSearchable = new AddToSearchable() };
    //When breakpoint is set, vm contains valid references
    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMyStuff(LookUpViewModel vm)
{
    //**Problem lies here**

    //Do backend stuff
}
```

Sorry for the lengthy post. I tried my best to keep it simple. Any suggestions you may have.. fire away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two methods to fix it:

1. You can add to do HiddenFor() for all properties of Model.Searchable.
2. You can use serialization to transfer your Model.Searchable into text  presentation and repair it from serialized form in controller.

Update: The problem is: You need to use @Html.HiddenFor(), not Html.HiddenFor();.

Comment: I attempted your first suggestion. Unfortunately, this did not fix my problem. Your second suggestion may work, but that would defeat the purpose of having a ViewModel.

Comment: what was the problem with first suggestion? Could you post view with this suggestion?

Comment: Although I feel that my previous implementation should work, I've updated my code to reflect this change.

Comment: Forgot to mention... I'm seeing the same problem as before. `LookUpViewModel.Searchable` is null while `LookUpViewModel.AddToSearchable` is valid.

Comment: Could you set breakpoint in your controller action and look what is in Request.Form.Keys? And what is in your hidden fields on client? Is there something?

Comment: There is only 1 key in Request.Form.Keys, and that is `AddToSearchable.Data`.

Comment: Oh I know what a problem: You need to use @Html.HiddenFor(), not Html.HiddenFor();.

Comment: That was it. For the record, HiddenFor() DOES need to be applied to each property. This was a nuisance for me only because my "Searchable" method actually has 25 properties. Update your answer and I will approve. Thanks for the help.